# re module Help Python

Tags: python, regex

How come this doesn't work? I'm getting <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00B66A68>

```
import re

mess = open('mess.txt', 'r')
text = mess.read()

result = re.search('[a-z]+[A-Z{3}]+[a-z{1}]+[A-Z{3}]+[a-z]',text)

print result
```

Comment: Which line throws the error, what exactly is the error, and what is the input? Please don't make us guess.

Comment: Now im getting this <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00B66A68>.

Comment: Please provide example input, and full output of running the script, i.e. the full traceback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[search](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) returns a corresponding [MatchObject](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) instance.

You need to add this to your code `result.group(0)`.

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search('(?<=abc)def', 'abcdef')
>>> print m
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x018ECF70>
>>> m.group(0)
'def'
```

Take a look here for [Python regex tutorial with re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

Advance answer for a possible NEXT question:

Your regex `'[a-z]+[A-Z{3}]+[a-z{1}]+[A-Z{3}]+[a-z]'` may not do what you think it is

Let's look at just part of it:

`[A-Z{3}]` matches one character out of 29 possibilities: `('A', ..., 'Z', '{', '3', '}')`

`[A-Z]{3}` matches exactly 3 capital letters.

Which do you want?

Next step: what do you expect `[A-Z{3}]+` to do?